# Can't install MailChimp API. Why?

Tags: nuget

I can't install [Mailchimp API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mcapi.net/) package using the command **Install-Package mcapi.net**. I get the following error.

```
PM> Install-Package mcapi.net
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'mcapi.net'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  mcapi.net
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

However, I can install this package using Nuget's UI. Odd. Why can't I install this package using the CLI?

Comment: Different package source selected in the Package Manager Console window?

Comment: You were right @MattWard. I didn't notice that the package source was coming from an internal nuget feed as opposed to the public nuget feed. Doh